# Default project in Visual C++ 2008

Tags: c++

In Visual C++ 2008 ( Professional Edition )it is impossible to create default project for a .cpp file. Sometimes it is inconvenient. Is there an edition of Visual C++ 2008 which allows it?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? What is it exactly that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: What do you mean by a "default project"?

Comment: Probably he meant a project wizard that will allow to choose already existing source files instead of generating default one.

Answer (score 1):

It's available, assuming you've already written the .cpp file.  Use File + New + Project From Existing Code.  You'll get a point-and-click wizard with a bunch of questions that need to be answered.

I reckon you'll use this a few times, then discover it is just simpler to start a new project from scratch with the Win32 Console Application template.  Just add your .cpp to the project's Source Files folder.

Comment: In Visual C++ 6.0 I open .cpp file and click Build without having created the project.  Visual C++ prints message box - Would you like to create default project workspace? Answer = Yes - default project will be created.

Comment: Yes, VC6 usually has to be pried from a programmer's dead fingers.  You are already very late, you'll have to get over it.

Answer (score 0):

Why you can't do this?

You can normally create Win32 C++ project and have with this .cpp file.

Answer (score 0):

You mean you don't want to create a solution each time?  There's no getting around this.  It can be useful to create a Sandbox solution and just fill that up with .cpp files to throw your ideas around on.

Comment: Alternatively, use a programmers text editor (such as NP++) for individual source files and only use a complete IDE when you are dealing with full projects.